# Customize page in concrete5

Tags: concrete5

I had created a custom page`(test)` in concrete5 through UI.

```
Dashboard->Sitemp->Addpage
```

I created a form in this page.After form submit I want to store those details in DB.I just want to where this page is saved in app folder structure.So that I can connet Db and save records.

Answer (score 1):

The page is not saved anywhere in the folder structure. It is saved in the database.
If you are using any of the forms add'ons however they will save the data in the db and you'll have access to it from the dashboard report section.
If you really want to be able to control it yourself then you will need to create a single page through code, add the form to it and write the code to process the page.

The single page would be in the single_pages folder and its controller in the controllers folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I created a page in single_pages folder how to access this page in my theme. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "my_profile" with your php file name following the instructions below:

> Sign in to the concrete5 dashboard, and go to Themes & Page Types > Single Pages. Find the "Add a Single Page" form at the bottom of the list, and enter "my_profile" at the bottom (or whatever the name of your single page.) Do not include ".php" in the field.

Per the instructions on Concrete5:
http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/pages/single-pages